# Circuit breaker for Scala and akka-http rest service

Tags: scala, akka, reactive-programming, akka-http

I am currently implementing a circuit breaker with Akka-HTTP as follows:

```
 def sendMail(entity: MyEntity): ToResponseMarshallable = {

      Thread.sleep(5 * 1000)
      validateEntity(entity).map[ToResponseMarshallable] {
        case (body, subject) if !isEmpty(body, subject) => {
          val mailResponse = sendMail(body, subject)
          OK -> ProcessedEmailMessage(mailResponse)
        }
        case _ =>
          BadRequest -> s"error: for $entity".toJson
      }
    } catch {
      case e: DeserializationException => HttpResponse(BadRequest).withEntity(HttpEntity(s"error:${e.msg}").withContentType(ContentTypes.`application/json`))
    }
  }

  val maxFailures: Int = 2
  val callTimeout: FiniteDuration = 1 second
  val resetTimeout: FiniteDuration = 30 seconds

  def open: Unit = {
    logger.info("Circuit Breaker is open")
  }

  def close: Unit = {
    logger.info("Circuit Breaker is closed")
  }

  def halfopen: Unit = {
    logger.info("Circuit Breaker is half-open, next message goes through")

  private lazy val breaker = CircuitBreaker(
    system.scheduler,
    maxFailures,
    callTimeout,
    resetTimeout
  ).onOpen(open).onClose(close).onHalfOpen(halfopen)

  def routes: Route = {
    logRequestResult("email-service_aggregator_email") {
      pathPrefix("v1") {
        path("sendmail") {
          post {
            entity(as[EmailMessage]) { entity =>
              complete {
                breaker.withCircuitBreaker(Future(sendMail(entity)))
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

My problem is that if i use `breaker.withCircuitBreaker(Future(sendMail(entity)))` the circuit breaker gets into an open state but the rest response returns `There was an internal server error` as a response

If instead I use `breaker.withSyncCircuitBreaker(Future(sendMail(entity)))` then the circuit breaker never goes in an open state but it returns the expected `HttpResponse`

Any thoughts on how can I solve this issue to trigger both the circuit breaker and also return a correct HTTP response ?

Comment: Can you also post the code that produces `breaker` ?

Comment: You need to use `onComplete` instead of `complete`.  The `complete` directive expects the response to be ready to go immediately.  On your case, `withCircuitBreaker` returns a `Future`, so `complete` won't be a valid option.  The `onComplete` directive is setup to work with a `Future`, so it's a better fit here.  Then inside the `onComplete` callback you can use `complete`.

Comment: @cmbaxter can you post an example, I'm failing to understand on how to bind/next the onComplete with complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
entity(as[EmailMessage]) { entity => ctx =>
  val withBreaker = breaker.withCircuitBreaker(Future(sendMail(entity)))
  val withErrorHandling = withBreaker.recover {
      case _: CircuitBreakerOpenException => 
        HttpResponse(TooManyRequests).withEntity("Server Busy")
  }
  ctx.complete(withErrorHandling)
}
```

Comment: It is not working, I get the same "There was an internal server error" message. I have tried to do some adjustments and the sendMail() method to return directly a future, if I don't wrap that in the circuit breaker it works and the future is resolved.

Comment: The send mail takes at least 5 seconds while your call timeout is 1 second. Wouldn't this cause an exception?

Comment: It should enter in an open state, which happens but no response is returned

Comment: I have removed the ```Thread.sleep()``` from the function call, and the response returns correctly. What I wanted now is just to return a HttpResponse from the ```onOpen``` function

Comment: You are right, I created a small app to test this and my first request works even if its takes longer then the timeout. Any subsequent request in the next 30 seconds will fail.

Comment: There I was wondering when the CB changes state, is there any way to still return HttpResponses ?

Comment: that's awesome, it works for the second run where the open is on, but for the first run it works regularly only if I remove the ```Thread.sleep()```, if ```Thread.sleep()``` is present in the code, it would still throw an ```"There was an internal server error."``` and does not return the actual ```HttpResponse```

Comment: You can add a `case ex => ...` to see if there is an other exception and handle it.

Comment: on the withErrorHandling block?

Comment: In the `recover` part

Comment: it was a TimeoutException that was not handled, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer another possibile solution as I believe that `onComplete` is the mode idiomatic way to go when dealing with the result of a `Future` when completing a route:

```
entity(as[EmailMessage]) { entity =>
  val withBreaker = breaker.withCircuitBreaker(Future(sendMail(entity)))

  onComplete(withBreaker){
    case Success(trm) => 
      complete(trm)

    //Circuit breaker opened handling
    case Failure(ex:CircuitBreakerOpenException) => 
      complete(HttpResponse(TooManyRequests).withEntity("Server Busy"))

    //General exception handling
    case Failure(ex) =>
      complete(InternalServerError)
  }
}
```